# Responsive Web Design - using px values

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

When creating a responsive website, I use percentage values for most `width` and `height` declarations.
How about `padding` and `margin` - is it ok to use `px` values there or should I also use percentages?

That both works is pretty clear, I am just concerned that some strange behavior of mobile phones (auto zoom or whatever, I don't know) messes something up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`px` is almost never the best answer. If by "percentages" you mean `.5em`, yes, that's usually best.

But device manufacturers have taken to lying to the browser about **everything**, so nothing will replace testing on the actual devices. As usual.

(Example: the iPad Mini has a physically smaller screen than the iPad, so you want to use bigger type; but there's no way for your code to detect that it's a Mini. Sigh.)

Answer (score 0):

You can however prevent alot problems by working according to W3C standards. Most browsers follow them and will prevent strange behaviour. Also try using mediaqueries in CS. They allow you to create different margins for smaller or different devices